# Powershell as scheduled task issue with importing module, it seems

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powercli

I am attempting to configure some powershell/view powercli scripts for our VMware horizon environment. I have a powershell script that works properly to query the horizon instance and check machine states. However, when I try to run this as a scheduled task using a service account, it seems to fail to import a module, as a command is unrecognized ("The term 'Connect-HVServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.")

I tried profiles as well, didn't matter.

What I observed is that if I open powershell as the user in question (run as different user > authenticate as service account), leaving that powershell instance open will allow the scheduled task to run as expected. However, if i close the powershell instance, the scheduled task fails. This is obviously not viable since the goal is for this script to run on a schedule without the service account (or any account) being logged into the windows server at the time the powershell script gets run.

Comment: if I open powershell as the service account, the script runs properly. If I leave powershell open (running in that user's context), then the scheduled task works.

Comment: Where's the module installed at? is it in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`

Comment: How is your action being called in your scheduled task?

Comment: @BenH the module for View PowerCLI is getting placed in the user's document folder.  
        Get-Module –ListAvailable VMware* | Import-Module
        Install-Module -Name VMWare.PowerCLI -RequiredVersion 6.5.1.5377412 –Scope CurrentUser –AllowClobber

Comment: @jrider calling a .bat file that contains: cd C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
powershell.exe "& "c:\programdata\vmware\scripts\AgentUnreachableRefreshDesktopWithCreds.ps1 -Execution"

Comment: @DonShappelle To test. On your action for `Program/script` do `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` then for your `arguments` do: `-NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File  "<Full path to ps1 file>"` . Run it manually and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: @jrider it finished rather quickly and I see no log file to suggest it ran.  Also, we have credentials stored so we have to run the powershell script with "-Execution", can I add that after "<path to file>" something like Bypass -File "c:\blahblah\blah.ps1" -Execution    ?

Comment: @jrider i added -Execution and I get a log output now: ERROR Could not execute in Execution mode.  Error Message was: Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of Bypass. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're running into is environment variables.  In the course of running as a user versus running as machine, the `PSModulePath` environment variable changes to include user-directories for user-scoped module installs.  You should install `PowerCLI` machine-wide.

Alternatives (these assume your service account has admin privileges):

- Modify your `$Env:PSModulePath` in the script to include each user's module path
- Specify the path in an `Import-Module` statement in your script before you use any of the cmdlets

---

Example of the first alternative:

```
foreach ($user in (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users)) {
    $Env:PSModulePath += ";$($user.FullName)\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
}
```

---

Example of the second:

```
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Users\KnownUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerCLI'
```

Comment: I tried method 2 and I think this may have helped. Thank you.

Comment: @DonShappelle Glad to be of service. If this solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer ✅